# Add options before select is expand and after select is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a html select I want to dynamic add options after it is click. and the options only be expand after they are loaded.

What I am want is like:

```
$(document).on("click", "MySelect", function(){
  // Load new options
  $("MySelect").load(url, changedFieldData, function(){
    // Expand after loaded.
    ExpandOptions();
  });
});
```

to load new options.
But the select always expand once I click on the select. Is there any way to delay the expand after the new options are loaded?

Comment: Can you please post the code where your new options are loaded? It'll help if you can post the dependent functional code.

Comment: Hi, the new options loaded by $select.load() function in my code

Comment: Are there any async function calls in your code?

Comment: $.load is async I think

Comment: I was asking about user-defined functions. Can you please post some functional block of code so that we can look into what's happening?
What we want to do here is call your ExpandOptions() only after new options are loaded. We can delay using a callback, but I'll have to look into your code to see which solution we can implement.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you load the options after mouse move instead?

```
<select id="MySelect" disabled>
    <option>Select</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(window).one("mousemove touchmove touchstart touchend", function(){
        $("#MySelect").load(url);
        $("#MySelect").attr("disabled", false);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Currently the logic is update the options after the select is clicked and before the new options expand.